# how to add shipping cost with product actual price? NEW

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm doing a website with woocomerce and i would like to add shipping cost fee to the product.
The product that i've got is product with variation.
Antoher way to say :  product 100$ + (product * 21% taxes) + shipping cost
I want : (product 100% + shipping cost) * 21% taxes.

I think that a part of solution is this:
[how to add shipping cost with product actual price?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27245789/how-to-add-shipping-cost-with-product-actual-price/28165795#28165795)

But i dont know how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Hi I m studying the plug in woo-distance-based-fee  but i need to change, in the cartshop i would like to add at product price  the fee.
Example: product price +FEE. How can i do it?

Comment: I think that the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60728760/woocommerce-zip-code-pricing-per-customer ask the similar question.

Comment: In that module in line 321 i see $cart_total_price = floatval( preg_replace( '#[^\d.]#', '', $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total() ) ); But i need to add at subtotal.

Comment: The answer of these question is these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77294767/add-a-custom-total-line-to-woocommerce-admin-order-totals