# Add a custom total line to WooCommerce admin order totals

Tags: php, woocommerce, admin, hook-woocommerce, orders

In WooCommerce, I would like to put an extra field in wc-order-totals.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_totals_after_discount', 'vp_add_sub_total', 10, 1);
function vp_add_sub_total( $order_id ) 
{
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    ?><tr>
    <td class="label">Subtotal-2:</td>
    <td width="1%"></td>
    <td class="total"><?php echo wc_price($order->get_subtotal($items_total+$shipping_total));?></td>
</tr><?php
}
```

How can I add the subtotal with shipping?

The values are already calculated previously.

[image: actually state of quotes]

So i need that subtotal-2 to be: 50.00€ + 33.60€

I need to calculate a second subtotal in WooCommerce, so the new field subtotal_2 must be cost of product plus shipping cost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will add a line to admin order totals, adding subtotal to shipping total:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_totals_after_discount', 'vp_add_sub_total', 10 );
function vp_add_sub_total( $order_id ) 
{
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="label"><?php _e('Subtotal-2')?>:</td>
        <td width="1%"></td>
        <td class="total"><?php echo wc_price( $order->get_subtotal() + $order->get_shipping_total(), array( 'currency' => $order->get_currency() ) );?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in aplugin). Tested and works.

Comment: Hello thanks you very much for the code. But now , im triyng to hide or unset the subtotal original.

Comment: How can i hidde order_shipping_line_items ?