# Hide original subtotal line from WooComerce admin order totals

Tags: php, css, woocommerce, admin, orders

These post is related with [Add a custom total line to WooCommerce admin order totals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77294767/add-a-custom-total-line-to-woocommerce-admin-order-totals/77294839#77294839)

Hello

I'm trying to hide Subtotal, but I can not find the class in CSS like:

```css
.cart-subtotal  { display: none; }
.order-total { display: none;    }
.order_shipping_line_items {display: none;}
```

It doesnt work.

Now I'm trying to unset with these code, but it doesn't work too:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'reordering_order_item_totals', 10, 3 );
function reordering_order_item_totals( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ){
    $shipping = $total_rows['line_subtotal'];
    $order_total = $total_rows['order_total'];

    unset($total_rows['line_subtotal']);
    unset($total_rows['order_total']);


    return $total_rows;
}
```

I try to reorder the fields and hide fields in the order of request.

[image: Subtotal Cart]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide original subtotal line From admin order total lines, use the following:

```php
add_action('admin_head', 'admin_head_shop_order_inline_css' );
function admin_head_shop_order_inline_css() {
    global $pagenow, $typenow;

    // Targeting WooCommerce admin single orders
    if ( in_array( $pagenow, ['post.php', 'post-new.php'] ) && $typenow === 'shop_order' ) :
    ?><style>table.wc-order-totals tr:first-child{display:none;}</style><?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Note: As all Admin Order total lines HTML are hard-coded in [this file](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/8.2/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-order-items.php#L156-L222), you can not reorder them.

---

To hide "Envio" shipping total line too, replace the code with:

```php
add_action('admin_head', 'admin_head_shop_order_inline_css' );
function admin_head_shop_order_inline_css() {
    global $pagenow, $typenow;

    // Targeting WooCommerce admin single orders
    if ( in_array( $pagenow, ['post.php', 'post-new.php'] ) && $typenow === 'shop_order' ) :
    ?><style>
    table.wc-order-totals tr:first-child,
    table.wc-order-totals tr:nth-child(4){display:none;}
    </style><?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.